# Regex that will list value between n and n+1 quotation mark in each line with specific beginning

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regex expression that will do the following task:

1. Check whether beginning of the line is e.g. "something"
2. go to nth quotation mark in the line
3. get the value between the nth quotation mark and n+1 quotation mark.
4. Go to next line
5. go to step 1.

I tried to make this work but honestly, I kind of do not fully understand the syntax and I am basically trying to join two or even more expressions written by someone else into one.

Would really appreciate answer that goes together with disection of every single step for the sake of me understanding the syntax a little bit better.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far. Adding sample input and expected result always helps. Have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `/^something(?:[^"]*"){n}([^"]*).*$/m`

Comment: its beter give you your sample

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex (for n==3):

```
^something.*$\n.*$(?:[^"]*"[^"]*){2}"([^"]+)".*$\n.*$
```

The value is in the first capture group. Mind the `/gm` modifiers.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/amQSgo/1

Answer (score 0):

You could check for each line:

```
^something([^"]*"){n}([^"]*)"
```

Maybe incomplete...

What it contains:

- first `^`: start of line
- `something`: the requested starting sequence of characters
- `([^"]*"){n}` n times some (possibly empty) text followed by a quotation mark
- `([^"]*)` The text following the n-th quotation mark until (exclusive) the n+1-th quotation mark
- `"` The n+1-th quotation mark
- `...` dont care what follows for the rest of line.

Use it on each line of text separately and check whether the expression produces a match. If it matches, the last match group is your requested sequence between `n` and `n+1` quotation marks. You can also produce a named match group to make life easier...